# How do you define an npm dependency nested in a git repo?

Tags: node.js, package, npm

If I have an npm dependency that is nested in a git repo, how would I define that dependency in the `package.json` file?

Say the git repo is at `git://github.com/user/myrepo.git` on the `dev` branch, at the relative path `./mylib` from the git repo's root.

Is this possible?

**Update:** found [this](http://debuggable.com/posts/private-npm-modules:4e68cc7d-1ac4-42d9-995a-343dcbdd56cb) which is *very* close to what I want. Now, I just need to know how to specify the path within the repo+branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. However, you could specify the repo as a dependency. Then add `mylib` to `bundledDependencies` in `package.json` and put a shim into `node_modules/mylib/index.js`:

```
module.exports = require('myrepo')
```

And yes, you don't need `..` or so, nodes magic does that for you.

Answer (score 0):

It is now pretty easy:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "sendwithus": "git+https://git@github.com/<repoowner>/<reponame>.git#<branch_name_or_commit-sha>"
    }
}
```